# How should I use NOT IN statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, notin

I am trying to use `NOT IN` statement with MySQL. However, I get 0 row with code below (no syntax error). I am sure there should be more than 0 row with the statement. What syntax should I adjust?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT member_id
FROM client_payments
INNER JOIN client_purchase_records ON client_purchase_records.id = client_payments.purchase_record_id
WHERE status = 1
AND client_payments.created_at > '2021-10-28 00:00:00'
AND client_payments.created_at < '2021-10-31 23:59:00'
NOT IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT member_id
    FROM client_payments
    INNER JOIN client_purchase_records ON client_purchase_records.id = client_payments.purchase_record_id
    WHERE status = 1
    AND client_payments.created_at > '2020-9-30 00:00:00'
    AND client_payments.created_at < '2021-10-27 23:59:00'
);
```

Difference about two query is mainly about created_at column, I want to do "set difference operation" with period A(2021-10-28 00:00:00 - 2021-10-31 23:59:00 )and period B(2020-9-30 00:00:00 - 2021-10-27 23:59:00)

1. I want to query out member_id who pay during 2020-9-30 00:00:00 - 2021-10-27 23:59:00
2. Subtract with member_id who pay during 2021-10-28 00:00:00 - 2021-10-31 23:59:00
3. Finally I get member_id who pay during 2021-10-28 00:00:00 - 2021-10-31 but not pay during 2020-9-30 00:00:00 - 2021-10-27 23:59:00 ( new member_id never show before)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your query is: "Find members like X that are not like X". What are you trying to get?

Comment: Please share more details. What do you want to achieve? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: `AND x < y NOT IN (SELECT whatever)` is wrong but **syntactically correct**. You are not getting syntax errors, yes, but the query is wrong.

Comment: Difference about two query is mainly about `created_at` column, I want to do "set difference operation" with period A(2021-10-28 00:00:00 - 2021-10-31 23:59:00 )and period B(2020-9-30 00:00:00 - 2021-10-27 23:59:00)

Comment: 1. I want to query out member_id who pay during 2020-9-30 00:00:00 - 2021-10-27 23:59:00
2. Subtract with member_id who pay during 2021-10-28 00:00:00 - 2021-10-31 23:59:00
3. Finally I get member_id who pay during 2021-10-28 00:00:00 - 2021-10-31 but not pay during 2020-9-30 00:00:00 - 2021-10-27 23:59:00 ( new member_id never show before)

Answer (score 0):

You presumably want to be saying `AND member_id NOT IN (...your subquery...)`; as is, it is using the previous condition instead of member_id.

Also, it looks like you want >= and <=, not > and <.

I would do this like so instead:

```
SELECT member_id
FROM client_payments
INNER JOIN client_purchase_records ON client_purchase_records.id = client_payments.purchase_record_id
WHERE status = 1
AND client_payments.created_at >= '2021-09-30 00:00:00'
AND client_payments.created_at <= '2021-10-31 23:59:00'
GROUP BY member_id
HAVING MIN(client_payments.created_at) >= '2021-10-28 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

> no syntax error

The error is in the logic.

Your condition, after adding the parenthesis according to operators priority, looks like

```
AND ( (client_payments.created_at < '2021-10-31 23:59:00') NOT IN ( {subquery} ) )
```

I.e. the result of comparing `client_payments.created_at < '2021-10-31 23:59:00'` (which is 0, 1 or NULL) is searching in the subquery output which is obviously illogical.